# My new drupal theme isnt showing up. How do I make a drupal theme show up after install or manual creation?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I created a child theme but it doesnt show up in the Admin section of available themes... what do I do?

Comment: I had this problem and this solution worked for me... Change the name of the .info file of your newly installed theme to match the directory name.  Also change the 'name' section *INSIDE* the .info file to match the  directory name of the new or child sub theme. Couldnt really find this so thought id help.

Comment: "Creating a theme" means you have completed everything, or else let us know what you did - created the .info file, where did you upload it, etc.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this?  My first comment was the answer but since I was new I couldnt answer it so  I put it in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem and this solution worked for me... Change the name of the .info file of your newly installed theme to match the directory name.  Also change the 'name' section *INSIDE* the .info file to match the  directory name of the new or child sub theme. Couldnt really find this so thought id help.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. The problem, it turns out, was that my theme name had a hyphen in it. Once I removed the hyphen, the theme showed up under 'Appearance'.